# LDAP custom users not able to authenticate on control center

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, openldap, confluent-control-center

I have deployed a LDAP server and integrate it with Kafka using RBAC.
When I try to login on control center with predefined users like Kafka, SR, C3 etc. defined under "dc=ldap,dc=example,dc-com". those are able to login but with custom users defined under "ou=users,dc=ldap,dc=example,dc=com" getting authentication error (invalid username and password).

Here is deployment used to deploy Kafka:

```
apiVersion: platform.confluent.io/v1beta1
kind: Kafka
metadata:
  name: kafka
  namespace: confluent
spec:
  replicas: 3
  image:
    application: confluentinc/cp-server:7.4.0
    init: confluentinc/confluent-init-container:2.6.0
  dataVolumeCapacity: 10Gi
  tls:
    secretRef: tls-group1
  listeners:
    internal:
      authentication:
        type: ldap
        jaasConfig:
          secretRef: credential
      tls:
        enabled: true
    external:
      externalAccess:
        type: nodePort
        nodePort:
          host: kafka.example.com
          nodePortOffset: 30000
      authentication:
        type: ldap
        jaasConfig:
          secretRef: credential
      tls:
        enabled: true
  authorization:
    type: rbac
    superUsers:
    - User:kafka
  services:
    kafkaRest:
      externalAccess:
        type: nodePort
        nodePort:
          host: kafka.example.com
          nodePortOffset: 30100
    mds:
      tls:
        enabled: true
      tokenKeyPair:
        secretRef: mds-token
      externalAccess:
        type: nodePort
        nodePort:
          externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
          host: kafka.example.com
          nodePortOffset: 30200
      provider:
        type: ldap
        ldap:
          address: ldap://ldap.confluent.svc.cluster.local:389
          authentication:
            type: simple
            simple:
              secretRef: credential
          configurations:
            groupNameAttribute: cn
            groupObjectClass: group
            groupMemberAttribute: member
            groupMemberAttributePattern: CN=(.*),DC=ldap,DC=example,DC=com
            groupSearchBase: dc=ldap,dc=example,dc=com
            userNameAttribute: cn
            userMemberOfAttributePattern: CN=(.*),DC=ldap,DC=example,DC=com
            userObjectClass: organizationalRole
            userSearchBase: dc=ldap,dc=example,dc=com
  dependencies:
    kafkaRest:
      authentication:
        type: bearer
        bearer:
          secretRef: mds-client
    zookeeper:
      endpoint: zookeeper.confluent.svc.cluster.local:2182
      authentication:
        type: digest
        jaasConfig:
          secretRef: credential
      tls:
        enabled: true
```

As per the above configuration only objects/users defined with "organizationalRole" object class and at "dc=ldap,dc=example,dc=com" this directory can only be able to authenticate on control center.
I have custom users at "ou=users,dc=ldap,dc=example,dc=com" this directory with object class "inetOrgPerson". I want to change the configuration, so that these custom users can also be able to authenticate on control center.

I have tried to change the configuration of LDAP in kafka deployment file, userSearchBase:ou=users,dc=ldap,dc=example,dc=com & userObjectClass: inetOrgPerson. but with configuration Kafka pod didn't come up and showing authentication failed error.

As per me Kafka & MDS both are taking same LDAP configuration to authenticate.
I tried to keep them separate by providing below given configuration to Kafka deployment.

```
identityProvider:
    type: ldap
    ldap:
      address: ldap://ldap.confluent.svc.cluster.local:389
      authentication:
        type: simple
        simple:
          secretRef: credential
      tls:
        enabled: true
      configurations:
        groupNameAttribute: cn
        groupObjectClass: group
        groupMemberAttribute: member
        groupMemberAttributePattern: CN=(.*),DC=ldap,DC=hcloneclick,DC=com
        groupSearchBase: dc=ldap,dc=hcloneclick,dc=com
        userNameAttribute: cn
        userMemberOfAttributePattern: CN=(.*),DC=ldap,DC=hcloneclick,DC=com
        userObjectClass: organizationalRole
        userSearchBase: dc=ldap,dc=hcloneclick,dc=com
```

but this configuration is ignored because RBAC is enabled. For Kafka authentication, MDS LDAP configuration is automatically used because of RBAC.